# What kind of animal is the beast of Gevaudan, exactly?

Tags: brotherhood-of-the-wolf

In the 2001 French film, [Brotherhood of the Wolf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotherhood_of_the_Wolf), we don't get to see the actual animal. Any hints or clues from any scene of the movie that can tell us what kind of animal the beast was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only times we ever get to see the supposed "Beast of Gévaudan" in the movie is in his armor/disguise, so it is really hard to tell what real animal was actually under this elaborate construction. The only hints we get from the movie, is that *Jean-François* brought it from his travels and from looking at the eyes I always assumed it was a tiger, albeit a somewhat unnaturally large one.

[image]

But [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotherhood_of_the_Wolf) is a bit more exact, claiming that it was a lion:

> It turns out the beast was an offspring of a "strange beast" that Jean-François brought back from Africa (**which director Christophe Gans insists is a lion**). It was tortured into becoming vicious, trained to attack humans, and dressed in metal armor plating and spikes along with a large mask and metal implants in its jaw to make it more formidable and frightening.

And the [interview with *Christophe Gans*](http://www.aintitcool.com/node/10793) on which Wikipedia's claim is grounded makes it quite explicit:

> **A.M:** What about the beast? Where did it come from?
>
> **C.G:** Well it's a lion!
>
> **A.M:** A lion?? the eye seemed more like a wolf ?!
>
> **C.G:** No it's a lion, it's supposed to be a lion, Jean-François de
>   Morangias (Cassel) brought it back from Africa, plus in the movie,
>   deFronsac says "it's a beast in an arnor", so it's fare to assume that
>   the unground people gave it it's armor... But you know, it's not
>   supposed to be realistic...

Comment: [The photo of the eye](http://img.xooimage.com/files69/e/0/1/33-2dabcd5.jpg). Clearly seems to be a lion in the movie.

Comment: @Goodzilla Indeed, I remembered this eye to be more colourful and tiger-like. And thanks for the picture.

Comment: I could have sworn it was a *[Liger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger)* as made famous by [Napoleon Dynamite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_Dynamite).